# Highest and lowest column values from multi index pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a multiindex dataframe, I need to get highest and lowest  scores as a dataframe

```
               score
date     asset       
01-01-16 XO         8
         VXO        3
         NP         4
         GE         2
         LE         1

import pandas as pd
pdf =pd.DataFrame({'date':['01-01-16','01-01-16','01-01-16','01-01-16','01-01-16'],'asset':["XO","VXO","NP","GE","LE"],'score':[8,3,4,2,1]})
    cdf = pdf.set_index(['date', 'asset'])
    cdf
```

I tried  cdf[(cdf.score < 2) & (cdf.score >4) ] which returns no values.

Expected output:

```
              score
date     asset       
01-01-16 XO         8
         LE         1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) for select by positions - first and last row:

```
cdf = cdf.sort_values('score', ascending=False).iloc[[0, -1]]  
print (cdf)
                score
date     asset       
01-01-16 XO         8
         LE         1
```

EDIT - You can also select index values by [`Series.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.idxmax.html) and 
[`Series.idxmin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.idxmin.html):

```
cdf = cdf.loc[[cdf.score.idxmax(), cdf.score.idxmin()]]  
print (cdf)
                score
date     asset       
01-01-16 XO         8
         LE         1
```

If possible multiple max and min values:

```
cdf = cdf[(cdf.score == cdf.score.max()) | (cdf.score == cdf.score.min()) ] 
print (cdf)
                score
date     asset       
01-01-16 XO         8
         LE         1
```

Comment: I had made the clarification on the question,I am not looking for head and tail value, rather I am looking for the highest and lowest values in score column.

Comment: That looks fine, but how do we get all values above 4, let say if have another score entry with 9

Comment: @Masterbuilder - I think your solution working nice, only need `|` for `OR` - `cdf[(cdf.score < 2) | (cdf.score >4) ]`